# Page shrinks when printing to Acrobat file - scale wrong

Tags: adobe-acrobat

When I print to an A4 pdf file, my scale has shrunk slightly. All page sizes are set correctly.

When I print direct to a printer, the scale is pretty accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'm answering my own question. This applies to CAD/GIS applications...

Firstly I found any changes to "Adobe PDF" settings should be made from (on windows) start>devices and printers>printer preferences for them to become default, and too even apply in most cases. If you are printing to A4, you may wish to change the default page size to the correct dimensions in mm while here. Not sure if this makes a difference, I was having the same problem both before and after changing the A4 size. The size may have been overstated in the defaults to prevent just this problem but it was not working for me.

Secondly when printing to the pdf file, set the page size to larger than the actual size you are printing too, EG A0 if you want to make an A4 plot. This ensures it can reach its intended size and does not get shrunk by Adobe Pro which seems to shrink the plot so it can fit the page within an added mystery margin. By setting a larger print page size, this extra Adobe Pro imposed margin is no longer a restriction and the plot will come out at the correct scale - the size your program wants it to be - not thankfully the size you set the page to in the print dialog. Your CAD/GIS program probably has already allowed for a margin such that your plot is a bit smaller than the intended page, however it may not have been enough to fit within the Adobe Pro imposed rules.

Finally, when printing the hardcopy, it is a simple matter to ensure no scaling is applied, plot is centered and hopefully the scale will be bang on.